# Jquery - Auto fills input base on insert value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form to input spouse details. The form is as below;

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="ic_no" id="ic_no" placeholder="IC No.">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="DOB" >
</div>
```

The ic_no will be like `870505113223`. I am able to get the first 6 digit which is our `YYYY-mm-dd` of birth;

**jQuery**

```
$("#ic_no").blur(function(){    
    var ic_no = $("#ic_no").val();
    var dob = ic_no.substr(0, 6);
    console.log(dob); //will output 870505
    $("#dob").val(dob); //this will give an error
});
```

My question is, how do I want to get the 6 digits to automatically fill the dob input?

From the above code, I will get this error,

```
The specified value "870505" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

Comment: convert and format `870505` to said format

Comment: *The ic_no will be like 870505113223. I am able to get the first 6 digit which is our YYYY-mm-dd of birth;*, **No first 6 digits aren't what you think they are**, the whole number is a milliseconds value of the date, you need to convert it back to a `Date` object and extract the dd, mm and yyyy values.

Comment: Instead of setting `870505` you need to set something like `1987-05-05` so `var dob = "19" + ic_no.substr(0,2) + "-" + ic_no.substr(2,2) + '-' + ic_no.substr(4,2)`

Comment: Thank you for the idea guys. @JacobDesight, what if for example, the year start with 2000? can I have a format like `87-05-05`?

Comment: @Amran Unfortunately no. But you can check if ic_no.substr(0,2) is less than 18 (2018 year) then add 20 else add 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `870505` matches the date `1987-05-05`.

You can do this :

```
var y = "19" + dob.substring(0, 2);
var m = dob.substring(2, 4);
var d = dob.substring(4, 6);
var f = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
$("#dob").val(f);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just one more, how to check if it is in year 2000 or 90's?

Comment: You can do it like this : `var y = parseInt(dob.substring(0, 2)) > 17 ? "19" + dob.substring(0, 2) : "20" + dob.substring(0, 2)`, it assumes that the highest possible year is `2017`, but this will ignore years like `1910`, I think you should change your whole logic to include the full year.

Comment: @chsdk do you have a reference or link if I want to include full year?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you cannot convert with the 6 digits only. you must get all the timestamp of your ic_no then convert it:

```
$("#ic_no").blur(function(){   
  var ic_no = $("#ic_no").val();
    d = new Date(ic_no),
    month = d.getMonth()+1, //it is begin with 0 so you must add 1
    day = d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear(); 

    month = CheckZero(month);
    day = CheckZero(day);

    //check if you can add 0 or not
    function CheckZero(number) {
       if (number < 10) {
           number = "0" + number;
       }
       return number;
    }

    var finished_date = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
     $("#dob").val(finished_date );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think the ic_no will give an invalid date.

Comment: Is it your ic_no value is `870505113223` then replace the `d = new Date(ic_no),` into `d = new Date(870505113223)`.